# ModelForm with OneToOneField in Django

Tags: django, one-to-one, django-forms

I have two models in Django that are related with a `OneToOneField` (`PrinterProfile` and `PrinterAdress`).
I am trying to do a form with `PrinterProfileForm`, but for some reason it does NOT pass the `PrinterAddress` fields into the form (it's not rendered by Django "magic" in the template).

What should I do so that my `PrinterProfileForm` include as well the fields from `PrinterAddress` (its related `OneToOneField`)?

Thanks a lot

```
class PrinterProfile(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=False, blank=False)
    additional_notes = models.TextField()
    delivery = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    pickup = models.BooleanField(default=True)


# The main address of the profile, it will be where are located all the printers.    
class PrinterAddress(TimeStampedModel):
    printer_profile = models.OneToOneField(PrinterProfile)
    formatted_address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=25, decimal_places=20)  # NEED TO CHECK HERE THE PRECISION NEEDED.
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=25, decimal_places=20)  # NEED TO CHECK HERE THE PRECISION NEEDED.
    point = models.PointField(srid=4326)

    def __unicode__(self, ):
        return self.user.username

class PrinterProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PrinterProfile
        exclude = ['user']
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You have to create second form for `PrinterAddress` and handle both forms in you view:

```
if all((profile_form.is_valid(), address_form.is_valid())):
    profile = profile_form.save()
    address = address_form.save(commit=False)
    address.printer_profile = profile
    address.save()
```

Of course in the template you need to show both forms under one `<form>` tag :-)

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ profile_form }}
    {{ address_form }}
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Life-saver...
Any idea why it's not taken care automatically by Django ModelForm?
Is it a design decision or some kind of bug?

Thanks

Comment: This is design decision. There is a lot of pitfalls in handling more than one model in single form (for example: how to handle model relations, how to handle fields with the same name in different models, how to set additional fields outside of the form).

Comment: Makes sense, though I understand that it works with ForeignKeys (inline_formset), so what is the difference with onetooneField?
It sounds less tricky to me, isn't it?

Comment: No, it doesn't work with inline formset.  Each form in formset handles only one "inline" model.

Answer (score 3):

Complementing the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27832125/4470542):

If you have custom clean methods, you need to add a `try/except` case. For the example presented if `address` had a `clean()` method to validate something you needed to change it to:

```
def clean(self):
    try:
        printer_profile = self.printer_profile 
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass
    else:
        ...code to validate address...
```