# Extends User profile in Django

Tags: django, django-profiles

I'm trying to make editable User profile and found, how to add some fields to it... But also I need to make editable first and last name, email and one field for change user password. Now I got only user and additional fields in my form...

How can I realise that?

My model:

```
import PIL

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class UserProfile(models.Model):  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    user_phone = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True, null=True)
    user_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='users', blank=True, null=True)
    user_balance = models.IntegerField(default=0)

User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u) [0])
```

My `forms.py` :

```
from django import forms
from userprofile.models import UserProfile

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('user', 'user_phone', 'user_picture', 'user_balance')
```

My view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.core.context_processors import csrf

# Create your views here.
from userprofile.forms import UserProfileForm
from userprofile.models import UserProfile

def user_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        user = request.user
        profile = user.profile
        form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile)

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = form

    return render_to_response('profile.html', args)
```

And my template:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field.error }}

{% endfor %}

<form action="/users/profile/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_ul }}

<input type="submit" value="Update" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cant call the user fields from the UserProfile then you can create a form for the User model

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('last_name', 'email', 'password')
```

You need to show both forms in your view also. Check this example [ModelForm with OneToOneField in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832076/modelform-with-onetoonefield-in-django)
For the password field you might need to do something like this, check the examples.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example

Comment: This is first I tried to do, of course)) That doesn't work...
`Unknown field(s) (user.last_name) specified for UserProfile`
And so on for all other fields...

Comment: OK, then, what you have to do is to create a second form for the model User, I update my answer so you can see it.

Comment: I don't understand, how to implement two forms to one view and render both on one page...:/

Comment: You have an example in that link I gave you, if all((profile_form.is_valid(), address_form.is_valid())):
    profile = profile_form.save()
    address = address_form.save(commit=False)
    address.printer_profile = profile
    address.save()
Of course in the template you need to show both forms under one <form> tag :-)

<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ profile_form }}
    {{ address_form }}
</form>