# Accessing field from OneToOne field in ModelForm

Tags: django

I am trying to extend Djangos authentication system and have a problem when trying to create the modelForm for it. As you can see below I have referenced the authentication backend via the suggested OneToOnefield however when I am creating the ModelForm if I try to reference the fields such as 'username', 'password' etc. it spits an error saying they are unknown fields. The form I am creating is a registration from. What am I doing wrong here? Cheers

Model -

```
class StudentModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    contact_number = models.IntegerField()
    referral = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=referral_choices)
```

ModelForm -

```
from django import forms
from opus_login.models import StudentModel, EmployerModel

class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = StudentModel
        fields = ['username', 'first_name']
```

Error -

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (username, first_name) specified for StudentModel
```

Comment: Those fields are on the User model, do you not just need your modelform to that model? `birth_date` and the other fields can't be null so showing those two fields on their own wouldn't work anyway

Comment: The ModelForm has access only to the model's Fields. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832076/modelform-with-onetoonefield-in-django

Answer (score 5):

A common solution when you need to extend the `User` model with another model is use two `ModelForm`s: one for `User` and another for extending model (`Student` in your case). In the first you access the needed fields of the `User` model, in the second those of the `Student` model.

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password',widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Repeat password',widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'first_name')

    def clean_password2(self):
        .......
        return password2

class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = StudentModel
        fields = ['birthdate', 'contact_number']
```

Then, in the view, you work with two forms instead of one. For example:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
        student_form = StudentForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid() and student_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            student_form.save()
```

And in your template you combine both forms in one:

```
<form action="." method="post">
  {{ user_form.as_p }}
  {{ student_form.as_p }}
  {% csrf_token %}
  <p><input type="submit" value="Register"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Hello, I have been trying to use your method as it seemed the most logical imo. However I have come across one problem being that you cannot modify the User model, for example I plan to add a clean() function for the password field however this wouldn't be possible with this method. Any suggestions?

Comment: @eZ_Harry I've edited the answer. You don't have to modify the `User` model because it has a password field.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly access One2One fields like this. You need to first create a object of `User` and add to One2One relation. You can try like this:

```
from django import forms
from opus_login.models import StudentModel, EmployerModel

class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField()
    first_name = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = StudentModel
        fields = ['__all__']

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        student = super().save(commit=False)
        user = User.objects.create(username=self.cleaned_data['username'], first_name=self.cleaned_data['first_name'])
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password']) #if there is a password field
        student.user = user
        student.save(commit=True)
        return student
```

Comment: I suppose `save()` method would raise an error when calling `super().save()` first, since it is a `ModelForm` and those fields are not in the model.