# ModelForm to edit a model and its OneToOne-related model

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, django-1.10

Say I have a User model and an Account model.

The Account is related to the User with a `OneToOne` relationship.

**I have a ModelForm for the User model, and I'm looking for a third-party plugin / patch / snippet to allow this declaration:**

```
class UserEditForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'account__phone']
```

*Note the `account__phone` part.*

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ModelForm with OneToOneField in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832076/modelform-with-onetoonefield-in-django)

Comment: I understand this cannot be achieved with the Django core, and thus looking for third party code.