# Extending User fields in UserCreationForm

Tags: django, forms

I am trying to add some custom fields to a `user`, and extend the `UserCreationForm` so that I can add these fields when the user is created. I am following the docs but when I try to load the page to create a user I get an error: `Unknown field(s) (username) specified for Customer`.

The docs that I am following: [Custom User and Auth Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-the-built-in-auth-forms)

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_restaurant = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.get_full_name()
```

forms.py

```
class CustomerSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = Customer
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('address',)
```

I understand that `username` is not part of the `Customer` class, but the docs appear to be doing the same thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The doc says:

> If your custom user model is a simple subclass of AbstractUser, then
>   you can extend these forms in this manner...

In other words this will work only in case you want to add to the form `is_restaurant` or `is_customer` fields:

```
 class CustomerSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('is_restaurant',)
```

But in your case `Customer` is not subclass of `AbstractUser`, since this method is not working for you. As a workaround you can try to work with two separate forms in the same time as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27832125/641249).

Comment: hello, thanks so much I was looking right past the fact that it wasnt subclassing `AbstractUser`. I will try the method in the link to the answer you provided, thanks again!